# SQL : update if present insert if not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a table in `SQL Server` I want to store usages of a discount code per person.

I have the following columns:

- Code
- UserId
- Usages

If the combination of code and `userId` is present I want to increase `Usages` by one, if not I want to insert a new record with `Usages` set to one.

Separate queries would be:

```
INSERT INTO CodeUsages 
VALUS (@code, @user, 1)
```

Or:

```
UPDATE CodeUsages
SET Usages = Usages + 1
WHERE UserId = @user
  AND Code = @code
```

Is there a way to combine these queries into one?

Comment: Check `MERGE` statement if you are using `SQL Server > 2005`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.CodeUsages
    WHERE UserId = @user
        AND Code = @code   
)
MERGE cte t
USING (
    SELECT UserId = @user, Code = @code
) s ON s.UserId = t.UserId AND s.Code = t.Code
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE SET t.Usages = Usages + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (UserId, Code, Usages)
        VALUES (s.UserId, s.Code, 1);
```

Comment: Could you explain what this query does ? I Don't understand what the WITH cte does.

Comment: It's just a restrict the number of target table records in a `MERGE` statement. In your case - 1 record

Answer (score 0):

I would use a try catch on Primary-key

`try
INSERT INTO CodeUsages 
VALUS (@code,@user,1)
catch
UPDATE CodeUsages
SET Usages = Usages + 1
WHERE UserId = @user
AND Code = @code`

- only PRIMARY-KEY your @code and @user